# Render html input based on request attributes

Tags: html, jsp, scriptlet

So I have a form which submits data to the server. After the submit some attributes are filled in on the request. I'd like to render or not render some elements on the page based on those attributes.

Basically I'd want something like this.

```
<% String productName = "";
    if( request.getParameter("productName") != null ){
                productName = (String) request.getParameter("productName");
    }
%>

<input type="text" id="product" name="Product" readonly="readonly" 
value="<%= productName %>" rendered="#{<%= productName %> not empty}"/>
```

Is that achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, did I really understand your question, but if I am, i think you already answered that :)

Just put the input text element into the condition, so if the productName is not null, then you show it, otherwise not.

If this is not the right answer for your questuion, please be more specific.

Comment: The rendered condition does not work the way it is now

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hide or show some input field based on the value of some parameter like `productName`. What you have write is correct but you need little modification to achieved this as show below :

```
<% 
   String productName = (String) request.getParameter("productName");
   if( productName != null && productName.length() > 0){
 %>
    <input type="text" id="product" name="Product" value="<%= productName %>" readonly="readonly"/>               
 <%                
    }
 %>
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of **Scriplet** that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Use `${param.productName}` to get the parameter value from request as shown below:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.productName}">
    <input type="text" id="product" name="Product" readonly="readonly" value="${param.productName}"/>
</c:if>
```